# How to save gns3 configurations in Ubuntu?

Tags: gns3

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to save my host configurations. I have assigned my hosts ip addresses but when I close gns3, the configurations are discarded. How to I save configurations?
[image: Network topology]

[image: Server configuration]

Comment: Did you do `copy running-config startup-config` in the switch?

Comment: What version of the GNS3 are you running?

Comment: @TDurden version 2.0.3

Comment: @RonMaupin No, I didn't

Comment: If you don't save your configuration in a switch or router, then you will not have it when it starts up again.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

In GNS3, by default, nothing will persist after reloading your project unless your Docker Container is configured to do so.  Your Docker Container may not be configured to have persistent data.  This behavior is described in the [official GNS3 documentation](http://docs.gns3.com/1KGkv1Vm5EgeDusk1qS1svacpuQ1ZUQSVK3XqJ01WKGc/index.html#h.7s4z7hjkewuv).

> PERSISTENCE
>
> By default nothing is persisted on disk. The container needs to be
>   designed for that.
>
> If in the Dockerfile the container mount volumes. GNS3 will create in
>   the project folders a folder for each Docker volume and will write
>   file inside.
>
> This mean if you use a container outside GNS3 the data will not be
>   available. But also this mean all the data of the GNS3 project is in
>   the same location.

Depending on your use-case, a simple work-around could be to use [VPCs](https://docs.gns3.com/1ALk8HxK9qPCjhNL2OzFtW64Z7b2kBwEnEe5xbPG2gJ0/index.html) or the pre-built [Ubuntu Docker appliance](https://docs.gns3.com/appliances/ubuntu.html) as hosts instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your hosts are TinyCore Linux machines. TinyCore restores files -including startup scripts- from an archive and configures itself with those scripts. You should alter startup scripts and save it into the backup archive.

- Edit /opt/bootlocal.sh and add your startup commands.

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # put other system startup commands here
  ifconfig eth0 172.16.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0
  ```
- Rebuild backup archive using *filetool* script. It creates a backup archive including files and directories listed in */opt/.filetool.lst* and excluding the ones in */opt/.xfiletool.lst* (/opt is already included so you don't need to edit anything.)

  ```
  filetool.sh -b
  ```
- Just in case

  ```
  sync
  ```
- Restart the node

Now your node should be having a persistent configuration.